# Indirection operator on const_iterator error

Tags: c++, llvm-gcc, llvm-clang, const-iterator

This code

```
std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& output, const Array& a) {
    if (a.empty()) {
        output << Structural::BEGIN_ARRAY << Structural::END_ARRAY;

    } else {
        output << Structural::BEGIN_ARRAY << std::endl;
        OutputFilter<Indenter> indent(output.rdbuf());
        output.rdbuf(&indent);

        for (Array::const_iterator i = a.begin(); i != a.end(); ++i) {
            if (i != a.begin()) {
                output << Structural::VALUE_SEPARATOR << std::endl;
            }

            output << *i; // <--- Error is here...

        }

        output.rdbuf(indent.getDestination());

        output << std::endl << Structural::END_ARRAY;

    }

    return output;

}
```

produces the following error in Apple LLVM compiler 4.2:

```
Indirection requires pointer operand ('Array::const_iterator' (aka 'int') invalid)
```

However, if I compile this code in LLVM GCC 4.2, it works fine. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the definition of `Array`?

Comment: typedef std::deque<Value> Array;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clean, Restart XCode, Clean, then Rebuild.

Comment: I also had to select the default language dialect and default standard library (if using default compiler).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `Array::const_iterator` is of type `int`. You cannot dereference an `int` (in contrast to a pointer or STL iterator).